# SSRS - broken/missing toggle images in html reports

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

- SSRS version is SQL 2005 x64 sp2 on Windows 2003 x64 sp2 and IIS 6
- Clients run IE 6 on a mixture of Win2k sp4 and WinXP sp3
- reports are accessed through the standard SSRS html viewer

As the title suggests my issue is that, in SSRS reports which use toggle buttons to control visibility of sections, the graphics for the toggle buttons will either not be shown or will be shown as broken links (with the standard IE missing image placeholder). In either case the toggling action continues to operate when the link is clicked.

This occurs approximately once for every five report executions.

I've used Fiddler to establish that whether the image link is broken or the image invisible, the browser is not requesting it from the server.

This sounds a lot like the IE "feature" described at http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;319546, which I've been bitten by before but was able to get around as I had control of the web-app source code.

In this case, the component is supplied by MS and the source is not accessible.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Do you have any suggestions how I might resolve it?

---

**Update:** I have tested this with SP2 + CU10, SP3 alone and SP3 + CU1 (CU 10 and CU 11 didn't make it into SP3, and are released in CU1 for SP3).

- SP3 seems to reduce the instance of
  the broken image fault
- Both SP2 +
  CU10 and SP3 + CU1 appear to
  eliminate the broken image fault.

However, in all cases, the invisible image problem continues to occur with about the same frequency. Short of a fix in a later CU, I don't have much hope of a complete solution.

Comment: What are you using for the image source of your images?   Are they embedded, project, or external?

Comment: These are the built-in expand/collapse (+/-) toggle images which SSRS provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this problem when we were having issues with our print control. Since we updated to the latest version of SSRS I haven't seen it again. Do you have the cumulative update for SP2 installed?

Comment: The DBA tells me we're on base SP2 with a single hotfix applied for a database engine issue on 64 bit. Do you know the number of the cumulative update which resolved the issue? I'm hoping it might be included in SP3.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956854 is the cumulative update I was talking about. Cumulative update package 10 for SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2. The specific fix replaced the print control since it had a known vulnerability and IE blacklisted the active x control.