# SQL Reporting Service Report Image Error

Tags: .net, image, reporting-services, rdlc

For a quick temporary solution I made an image of a form that the users wanted to have programatically filled out. I then embedded that image in a report and filled the page with the image. I then put the fields on top of the image to fill out the areas in the form that needs filling. I realize this may not be the best solution, but it worked and we needed to get something working in just a couple days and as long as the user exports it to PDF, it works fine.

Normally there are only a few pages, but today they have almost 40 pages. The problem is that after about page 35, the image becomes a small red X (like when an image is missing on a web page) but it will still print the text that goes on top of the image.

To add to my confusion, after a couple tweaks of how it page breaks, the report will run fine on my PC but not on the server. This report is using the Visual Studio reports and are stored on the intranet server not the SQL Server.

The image is about 250k and is a PNG.

I hope I have explained this clearly. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe the fix for this was to [create a PDF through code][1] instead of through the viewer. 

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I fixed this by [creating a PDF through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background) instead of using the report viewer. I haven't found a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

could it be something along the lines of the http request is getting to large when your hitting the 35th page. I think the default http request size is 4mb on most asp.net applications. It might have logged something into the app log.

you can increase the size of the max http request by editing the machine.config file see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL 2005, you may find you can improve matters by upgrading to SP2 + CU10 or SP3 + CU1.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510978/ssrs-broken-missing-toggle-images-in-html-reports), which helped me resolve part of a similar issue.

Comment: We are running SQL Server 2008. However, these are RLDC reports, so they are running on the web server not the SQL server.