# ssrs-Image url-It is all ok while opening report but when i export it to pdf image couldnot be viewed

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am using ssrs for the reporting .I am sending parameter list including image url as a parameter. My report is unable to show image while rendering .

- My image is in root folder of my web app.
- i have sent image url like this

---

```
            string path = "http://" + Request.Url.Host;
            path = path + ":" + Request.Url.Port;
            path = path + "/Image/Logo.png";
            querystrings.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Logo_Url", path));`
```

- It is all ok while opening report but when i export it to pdf image couldnot be viewed.

---

I hope my question is clear. I have tried hard to make to clear so that i could be helped.
thank you in advance.

for more clearance to my question

```
Report.ServerReport.SetParameters(lst1);
byte[] b = Report.ServerReport.Render("PDF");Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
Response.End();
```

This is how i export my report to pdf. Hope i ll get some idea around this

Comment: So the preview in your ReportViewer is ok and the problem is only when you export to PDF? What happened if you try to export to Excel or Word?

Comment: same problem image is not loaded. :(

Comment: Is everything ok when you preview your report in ReportViewer?

Comment: yes tezzo its all fine here with ReportViewer. And now am trying to add image folder to the report server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**after all this i come to the solution**

---

- created a folder for my image in report server
  [image]

---

- then i create a execution account.***Use acount having reading only property avoid using account having high permissions***[image: Use acount having reading only property avoid using account having high permissions]

---

**And** i got what i was looking for .

Answer (score 0):

If everything is ok when you preview your report in ReportViewer, maybe is a permission problem.

Check external images section in this document: [Adding Images to a Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156482%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

> When the report is previewed in Report Designer, preview uses the
>   credentials of the user to display the image. When the report is run
>   on the report server, the report server uses the unattended execution
>   account to retrieve the image. If the unattended execution account is
>   not specified, the image is retrieved using no credentials (anonymous
>   user account). If either of these accounts have insufficient rights to
>   access the image, the image will not be displayed in the report. For
>   more information about the unattended execution account, see
>   Configuring the Unattended Execution Account.

Comment: its a server report and if it is redered to the html, than rendering to "pdf" is just it byte conversion isn't it??

Comment: yes, you're right! I confused Report Designer and Viewer. What happend if you manually export your rdlc to PDF (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background)?

Comment: i hav added my code for export to pdf please review it. Its okie for rendering all except image for my logo.

Comment: finally i have published image folder in report server and i specified unattended execution account. It works :)