# RDLC generate PDF

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I'm looking for guidance or and idea to generate PDF through RDLC report without using `reportviewer`. The PDF must be saved in the local specified path. I've been trying for 1 week but I'm still unable to find a solution.

Comment: solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background

Comment: Dear Agent.Realy thanks for your help. i have  total 2700 student. each student i want to generate individual PDF report. first, i retrive the data from table and bind in datasource (like normal procedure to generate RDLC). after that i can run below code rite?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link helps 
[RDLC to PDF](http://forums.asp.net/t/1556522.aspx?RDLC+Export+directly+to+Excel+or+PDF+from+codebehind)

This is how you render to pdf... updated for completeness sake

```
private void CreatePDF(string fileName)
{
    // Variables
    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamIds;
    string mimeType = string.Empty;
    string encoding = string.Empty;
    string extension = string.Empty;


    // Setup the report viewer object and get the array of bytes
    ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
    viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "YourReportHere.rdlc";


    byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);


    // Now that you have all the bytes representing the PDF report, buffer it and send it to the client.
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = mimeType;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "." + extension);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
    Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
}
```

Comment: while this link might help with the case, links often die and in that case your answer will become useless. It's always advisable to add a little detail on how the link helps

Comment: The earlier link already solve my issue (agent5566). anyway thanks. The link help me to Render the RDLC to convert to PDF. there rest i just folow standard code which i done earlier.