# Generate PDF from RDLC report in winform

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

How to programtically generate and save the PDF report from RDLC report?

I did this in web application and it works using below statement:

```
      Dim fileContent As Byte() = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamIds, _
            warnings)
```

Can any one guide me best way to achieve this in winform.

when use same approach then getting error `Defination of the report is invalid`.

`REport viewer version 10.0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a PDF from a RDLC Report in the Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Report was created in vs 2008 but, opened in vs 2013 and trying to generate PDF using Microsoft ReportViewer winform dll 10.0 so, that happened.

Its fixed by, opening old report file into VS 2010 and made related changes and use that one in visual studio. so, Microsoft Report viewer winform dll 10.0 is able to open this report.

its solved.

Thanks