# Generate PDF reports from SQL Server reports.rdl C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, pdf, reporting-services

Let me start by asking for your patience as I am ignorant of SSRS and not so sharp on the WCF technology that I intend on using to perform the task I want.

I have a SQL Server Express instance with data I want to get daily reports out of. I can not schedule tasks on SQL Server (and the reports server I think I can in the full blown but not in Express) , but I can schedule via windows task.

So I am writing an application that will use predefined rdl's  to generate my reports and send the reports back via email. I am not sure how rdl's data connection is set from my C# application - I created rdl's in its own project, but it looks like I need to do rdlc conversions for my application.

What I would like to do is query the database via the reports and then send those reports out in an email to a set group of recipients (pulled from their email field in the users=reports result table.

[FYI] I also have a web application that might need to generate these same reports.

**Now on to my question:**

I am not sure if I even need WCF to do anything here, as it looks like from this post  [Creating a PDF from RDLC report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background/2686205) that I can simply run that code and point to my data source and the bytes will be returned to me (so far fine for a desktop quick and dirty getter - I think)

Now is the same functionality possible in a web application - it would be nice to reuse the same code.

Can some one provide me with some proper guidance for this kind of functionality with the technologies involved - so I can code something proper and maintain KISS  principle.

Comment: This is all available through SSRS Subscriptions, take a look at this article- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872783.aspx

Comment: @newGuy Just like OP said, they have the Express edition of SQL. I doubt you can do subscriptions with it.

Comment: Not really sure what your question is.  You have code provided in the link.  What's the problem?  Have you tried it?  Just create a console app and try the code out.  You'll need to find the assembly `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms` or `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms`.

Comment: @RickS I am very new to SSRS reporting - I am thinking my rdl's are simply code that is compiled and becomes part of my application and not pushed to the SQL Server ? I am also thinking with the example - that wcf is not needed to transfer the byte data of the PDF , I can get that directly. I admit I am confused which is why my question is lacking in clarity. I intend to try the sample - building that now - but want to make sure that I do not make it complicated or get 'stuck' just because of my lack of knowledge it's a dark box to me, maybe you have been in this place and can relate.

Comment: @newGuy RickS is correct subscriptions are not supported in the community edition - the fling for the real edition is too costly considering the number of tables and rows ; we are talking about 400 rows per year in one table , one additional table with 400 rows and then 5 tables with ~ 100 rows each. but the reports are desired and SSRS rdl files make it snappy to get the PDF report. Otherwise I need to go the html then html2pdf route. I prefer not too as the rdl allows for someone other than me to design.