# Change default name reportViewer asp.net Mvc from code behind before export

Tags: asp.net, report, export-to-excel, rdlc, export-to-pdf

Good morning guys,
in my application asp.net MVC rdlc reports form through reportViewer.
The file export feature in the formats: pdf, xlsx, docx, by default, assigns the name of the rdlc file, so if, for example, my rdlc file is called ReportPippo.rdlc, I will get the export report, depending on of the chosen format: ReportPippo.pdf, ReportPippo.xlsx, ReportPippo.docx.
Is it possible to dynamically change the filename by not using the default name?
I would like to get something that gives a date / time to the filename so that I have a different file every time I print.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the file name at runtime with the `LocalReport.DisplayName` property.