# Build simple multi page PDF with RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc

Is it possible to create a simple multi page PDF file with a RDLC report?
By simple PDF file, I mean a report that doesn't have any group or detail. Just some text that I wrote in the designer.

What I have tried so far:

1. I added a header to the report and let the body of the report empty.
2. I set the report format PageSize property to 8.5in by 11in
3. I expanded the header height to 22in (So should be 2 pages total..)
4. I added some textboxes all over the Header

Expected result when I render the report to PDF: A PDF file with 2 pages (8.5in by 11in each) of text.

What I actualy get: A PDF file with a single 8.5in by 22in page of text.

It seems like the PaperSize is ignored.

Comment: Have tried to search?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background

Comment: Yes but this doesn't answer my question. I know how to create a PDF from a RDLC report. What I want is to create a report with no tablix or data. Just 2 pages of text. I am having a hard time getting the text to appear on 2 different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `TextBox` with `CanGrow` property set to `True` inside a `Body` whose height is higher (2x) than `Page` height.

Please note that you can view the final effect only in `Print Layout` mode of `ReportViewer`.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Only problem is that a blank page appear after every page. So my 2 pages become 4. Also, I can control the page break location by adding rectangles in the Body and settings its pageBreak property.

Comment: check your right/left margins if a blank page appears after every page. probably body width + right/left margins exceed page width.