# SSRS 2016 Report - Populate table from string parameter

Tags: string, reporting-services, datasource, rdl, ssrs-2016

Let's assume I have the following C# object:

```
 public class BusinessDetails
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        public string Address2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Long story short my solution [A] sends a serialised (JSON) `List<BusinessDetails>` to another external solution [B] that in turn feeds the RDL in question with this and other provided parameters (strings); therefore, on the RDL level I am limited to strings and strings only.

This is all good for simple, one value string parameters but I am interested in dynamically populating table from (JSON 'flattened'/string) `List<BusinessDetails>` in the mentioned RDL.

I see the available parameter types are:

- Text
- Boolean
- Date/Time
- Integer
- Float

I guess my question is - can I use the Text/string param to dynamically populate a table in RDL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short anser NO!
long answer: you dont need that, using the report viewer control you can use the list directly as datasource, when using rdlc instead of rdl you can even consume the class in the reportdesigner, you dont have to come up with ways to align your data source mapping with the data you are recieving
read this for further info: [Creating a PDF from a RDLC Report in the Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background)

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestions will not be possible in my scenario. The problem is, my solution [A] makes a serialised (JSON) POST to another external solution [B] that in turn feeds the RDL in question with the provided parameters (strings), therefore I am limited to strings and strings only. The [B] is not aware (and won't be) of specific types/classes that [A] operates with. 
I take it somehow transforming the string paramter (that contains the serialised list) into a data source is not an option, and cannot be achieved in within the RDL template with a bit of extra code?

Comment: you can't get a datasource from a parameter in ssrs., what you have to do is either edit the rdl before generation (using the enderdata datasource), or weave code around the rdl so its datasource is properly filled

Comment: I have asked: 'I take it somehow transforming the string parameter (that contains the serialised list) into a data source is not an option, and cannot be achieved in within the RDL template with a bit of extra code?'... to which you replied: weave code around the rdl so its datasource is properly filled. I mean can you possibly be any more vague?

Comment: i dont have enough information to be less vague, can you edit the rdl in runtime? can you deploy other data extensions to the external solution? what is the external solution? ssrs? or some custom code you cannot change, etc., why do you need the external solution anyway, when you can generate pdfs from rdl in your process using my suggestion