# Producing a Form from an Overlay from Reporting Services rdlc Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, overlay, rdlc

I am not sure what you call it in other technologies, on the IBM i (or iSeries) we call it overlays. The overlay is an image of a form that is stored on the server then a program generates the form with fields from the database so you can eliminate preprinted forms.

I had a [problem last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970698/sql-reporting-service-report-image-error) with the method I was trying at the time. It was a rush job at the time to be revisited at a later point. The work-around at the time was to export to PDF. So now it is "later" and once again is a rush (imagine that). This is all done through a web-based interface.

So how do you generate forms from something that was once a preprinted form? What method do you recommend? This is a legal form and must be filled out a certain way and can have many in a batch (up to 50 or so). I would prefer to not have them print one page at a time.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

UPDATE: I found [this article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Gogolowicz-Swanson-SSRS) which may help some. It seems to confirm I am doing this right.

Comment: Could I send multiple files straight to a default printer in a web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article I mention above got me in the right direction.